# Сохранение Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookie

Здравствуйте!

Нужно, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу запоминался выбранный класс.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="js_selectAnimate">SELECT ANIMATION / ВЫБЕРИТЕ АНИМАЦИЮ:
    <div class="js_default js_active">DEFAULT</div>
    <div class="js_zoomIn">ZOOM</div>
    <div class="js_rollIn">ROLL IN</div>
    <div class="js_lightSpeedIn">LIGHT SPEED</div>
    <div class="js_fadeIn">FADE IN</div>
    <div class="js_fadeInLeft">FADE IN LEFT</div>
    <div class="js_fadeInRight">FADE IN RIGHT</div>
    <div class="js_fadeInUp">FADE IN UP</div>
    <div class="js_bounceInLeft">BOUNCE IN LEFT</div>
    <div class="js_bounceInRight">BOUNCE IN RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.js_selectAnimate div').on("click", function() {
    var ActiveAnimate = "js_active";
    $('.js_selectAnimate div').removeClass("js_active");
    $(this).addClass(ActiveAnimate);
    $.cookie('js_activeAnimate', 'js_saveActiveAnimate');
    $.cookie('js_classActiveAnimate', ActiveAnimate);
});

if ($.cookie('js_activeAnimate') == 'js_saveActiveAnimate') {
    $('.js_selectAnimate div').addClass($.cookie('js_classActiveAnimate'));
}
```

Сейчас при переходе на другую страницу ко всем .js_selectAnimate div добавляется класс .js_active, а нужно, чтобы добавлялся только к выбранному ранее классу.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что не имеет смысла сохранять в Cookie активный класс, который известен и не меняется, лучше сохранить класс того дива, который должен быть активен. Попробуйте использовать такой код для этого:

```
$.cookie('js_classActiveAnimate', 'js_default'); // Если нажатия не было, то будет активным дефолтный див
$(".js_selectAnimate div").on('click', function() {
    var activeDivClass = $(this).attr('class');
    $(".js_selectAnimate div").removeClass('js_active');
    $(this).addClass('js_active');
    $.cookie('js_classActiveAnimate', activeDivClass);
});

$('.js_selectAnimate div').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass($.cookie('js_classActiveAnimate'))) { // Находим див, у которого класс совпадает с сохранённым в Cookie
       $(this).addClass('js_active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Alex вы действительно мастер! Спасибо, все работает!